# jquery stopped working Error: TypeError: $(...).html(...) is null

Tags: jquery

I run a simple jquery code on a page. There are other scripts as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var val = $('#order-pane-ship_to').html().split('<br>')[2]
var matches = val.match(/\d+/g);
if (matches == null) {
alert('error');
}
});
```

The code looks inside certain element. On pages that do not contain element I get error in console - Error: TypeError: $(...).html(...) is null. Moreover some other scripts stop working. Error is pointing to second line with selector. I assume that this is because script can not find the element on some pages. What can I do to remove this error? Thank you

I have to use jquery 1.3.2

Comment: Is this the actual code? Because you're missing a closing brace on your `if` statement. Also, do you know for sure that there is going to be at least 3 elements in the result of `split('<br>')`

Comment: sorry, I copied it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self explanitory. The result of `$('#order-pane-ship_to').html()` is `null`. You need to test it first:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var html = $('#order-pane-ship_to').html();
    // Make sure this returns a non-null, non-empty value before we do any work on it
    if(html) { 
        var val = html.split('<br>')[2]
        var matches = val.match(/\d+/g);
        if (matches == null) {
            alert('error');
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("no html");
    }
});
```

There are also a few other issues with this code:

1. You are assuming that `html.split` is going to return something. It might not, unless you know exactly what the HTML of this element is going to be.
2. You shouldn't use match if you don't care about the data it returns. You should use [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead.

Comment: +1, but I'd rather see `test` inside the code snippet, not as a sidenote, nobody (of those who use `match`) reads sidenotes. )

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#order-pane-ship_to').length){
        var val = $('#order-pane-ship_to').html().split('<br>')[2]
        var matches = val.match(/\d+/g);
        if (matches == null) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: @raina77ow That's really a separate issue. @rajesh, `.html` returns null even if the element doesn't exist so there's no need to call two separate selectors

Comment: Of course that's a separate issue. Still, using String#match when RegExp#test clearly suffices is like hitting a nail with a (heavy) screwdriver. It'll work, sure, but that's not what screwdriver is for.

Comment: Agreed. Not that it shouldn't be mentioned of course, but you can't expect the answerer to fix all of the issues in the OPs code - because there's more than just that one!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var val="";
if($('#order-pane-ship_to').html())
{
val = $('#order-pane-ship_to').html().split('<br>')[2]
}
var matches = val.match(/\d+/g);
if (matches == null) {
alert('error');
});
```